# Multiple layouts not working under react router 4 and redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to apply two layouts on diffrent routes.
However, the this.props.children doesn't show the container as expected.
In short, this.props.children is null in the layout.

How to make multiple layouts work?

## NPM versions

```
├─┬ @types/react-router@4.0.15
│ ├── @types/history@4.6.0
│ └── @types/react@15.6.4 deduped
├─┬ @types/react-router-redux@5.0.8
│ ├── @types/history@4.6.0 deduped
│ ├── @types/react@15.6.4 deduped
│ └── redux@3.7.2 deduped
```

## Router

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <MainLayout exact path="/" component={IndexContainer as any}/>
                        <MainLayout path="/index.html" component={IndexContainer as any}/>
                        <CheckoutLayout path="/checkout/:slotDetailId" component={CheckoutContainer as any}/>
                        <Route component={NotFound}/>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
    ,
    document.getElementById('quickpass')
)

export default class MainLayout extends React.Component<any, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Banner />
                    {this.props.children}
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export class CheckoutLayout extends React.Component<any, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Banner />
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

## Update

The request `http://quickpass.com/checkout/762` always match the MainLayout
Any idea?

```
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" component={MainLayout} />
                        <Route path="/checkout" component={CheckoutLayout} />
                        <Route component={NotFound}/>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>



        export default class MainLayout extends React.Component<any, {}> {
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <Header />
                        <Banner />
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path='/' component={IndexContainer}/>
                            <Route exact path='/index.html' component={IndexContainer}/>
                        </Switch>
                        <Footer />
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }

        export class CheckoutLayout extends React.Component<any, {}> {
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <Header />
                        <Banner />
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path='/checkout/:slotDetailId' component={CheckoutContainer}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Switch` should be

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" render={(props)=><MainLayout><IndexContainer/> <MainLayout/>}/>
    <Route exact path="/index.html" render={(props)=><MainLayout><IndexContainer/> <MainLayout/>}/>
    <Route path="/checkout/:slotDetailId" render={(props)=><CheckoutLayout><CheckoutContainer/> <CheckoutLayout/>}/>
    <Route component={NotFound}/>
</Switch>
```

You can pass the `props` from the `render` method into your layout or children as required.

Edit: *The other way*  :)

You can partition your `Routes` between the components. Your root component would render the `Routes` for your layout components. The layout components will render the `Routes` for the child components which should show the layout.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={MainLayout}/>
                        <Route path="/checkout" component={CheckoutLayout}/>
                        <Route component={NotFound}/>
                    </Switch>
            </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
    ,
    document.getElementById('quickpass')
)

export default class MainLayout extends React.Component<any, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Banner />
                    <Switch> 
                        <Route exact path='/' component={IndexContainer}/>
                        <Route exact path='/index.html' component={IndexContainer}/> 
                       //Any other routes that need to load this layout go after this
                    </Switch>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export class CheckoutLayout extends React.Component<any, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Banner />
                <Switch> 
                        <Route exact path='/checkout/:slotDetailId' component={CheckoutContainer}/> 
                       //Any other routes that need to load this layout go after this
                    </Switch>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: any other way to write this feature. it's not so...readable!! thanks anyway :)

Comment: Updated answer to show another way of writing this feature.

Comment: The request `http://quickpass.com/checkout/762` always match the MainLayout
Any idea? You could check my update~ thanks so much

Comment: Seems to work for me when I created this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/kmk034yj3v . Can you check and reproduce your issue here? If not might need to look at the store. Also, please remove the `Router` under `ConnectedRouter` in the root of the application. I don't think that is needed.

Comment: My bad. i should add 'exact' for the index route ~ thanks so so much!